# View Could Not Be Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In a ASP.NET MVC website; does every view need to have a corresponding/associated Model and Controller?

I am building the bare bones of my website; so I have created all the views but not the Models or Controllers yet. I want to be able to view a page (that contains no content associated with a model or any functionality that a controller should handle - yet). So at this point every view (cshtml page) is a static HTML page.

But when I go to access any view/page I get the error:

> The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /TeamMember/raiseIssue

raiseIssue.cshtml content:

```
@{
    Layout = "layouts/main.cshtml";
}
<form action="@ViewBag.PostUrl" method="post">
    <div class="row feedback-input text-center">

         <textarea name="Text"></textarea>  
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-standard">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In order to navigate to `TeamMember/raiseIssue` you need a method `public ActionResult RaiseIssue()` in `TeamMemberController`

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to navigate to the view directly with your browser?

Answer (score 0):

MVC do not allows to browse the view directly. What you can do is create empty controller method like below

```
public ActionResult RaiseIssue()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

in controller TeamMemberController

One other thing, please make sure that proper route are configured in RouteConfig.cs

I hope using this method you will be able to browser the view with writing much code in controller or model/